# Wordpress - Stream Video Player - Large flv files

Tags: video, video-streaming, wordpress, video-encoding

I need to enable locally hosted video player in a wordpress site.  Currently I am using the 
[steam video player plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stream-video-player/).  It seems to work fine for small files, and large files simply stalls as they take too long to load.  See examples [here](http://kalammagazine.com/?page_id=12).  How to handle this situation.  Are there any alternative plugins or file formats that I should consider?  Is this a hosting issue?  Thank you your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to you that you use JWplayer. He is very effective and professional, you shipment here the URL so that you see and download it, is of free use. I hope helped.

URL: http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/

Bye!

Comment: I use JWPlayer myself, but don't think it will help here. Use is not free for commercial sites, with a very broad definition of "commercial". Also it's not sure whether using a different player solves the OP's problem - I'm pretty sure it doesn't

Comment: This in not a commercial site. Will try this plugin.

Comment: The person that I need the not specified aid to if she is for commercial use or no. Anyway if he is ethical or I have not seen but it using commercial companies without paying license some.

Comment: Clearly. Then that is why you can use it! I hope that you have success with, is very effective

Answer (score 2):

I have used this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/

with a files between 100 and 300 mb without issues. You can see if that can help.